# Sending location with get

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am making a simple app that sends location data to a server using http get request.
The problem is that the request is made only on the first time despite the fact that it is inside the positionchanged event handler.

Here is my code. I can't find what is wrong with it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Device.Location;

namespace kechap
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        GeoCoordinateWatcher gw = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();

        Uri url = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload/1e3fae069dd62fa1641183cd77092ed2053a0e75/1/2");


        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            gw.MovementThreshold = 10;
            gw.PositionChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                MyMap.Center = e.Position.Location;
                MyPushpin.Location = e.Position.Location;

                WebClient wc = new WebClient();

                wc.OpenReadAsync(url);
                wc.OpenReadCompleted += (ss, ee) =>
                {
                };          
            };

            gw.Start();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess I would say the URI, which in the code you have posted does not change between calls, is resolved from cache after the first time. I suggest you use the age old hack of appending a parameter and giving it a value that changes with each invocation (eg the position you seem to want to report).

Comment: That's something I didn't predict. I had the url fixed to test if it works and this failed me.

Comment: In the early days of web apps cacheing was the bane of my existence. There are a bunch of ways to inhibit it, ranging from diddling the URL (as I have already suggested) to assorted HTML meta tags and directives. Diddling the URL is ugly but reliable. The down-side is it bloats the browser cache.